# Can this loop be sped up in pure Python?

Tags: python, testing, performance, timing

I was trying out an experiment with Python, trying to find out how many times it could add one to an integer in one minute's time. Assuming two computers are the same except for the speed of the CPUs, this should give an estimate of how fast some CPU operations may take for the computer in question.

The code below is an example of a test designed to fulfill the requirements given above. This version is about 20% faster than the first attempt and 150% faster than the third attempt. Can anyone make any suggestions as to how to get the most additions in a minute's time span? Higher numbers are desireable.

**EDIT 1:** This experiment is being written in Python 3.1 and is 15% faster than the fourth speed-up attempt.

```
def start(seconds):
    import time, _thread
    def stop(seconds, signal):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        signal.pop()
    total, signal = 0, [None]
    _thread.start_new_thread(stop, (seconds, signal))
    while signal:
        total += 1
    return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Testing the CPU speed ...')
    print('Relative speed:', start(60))
```

**EDIT 2:** Regarding using `True` instead of `1` in the while loop: there should be no speed difference. The following experiment proves that they are the same. First, create a file named `main.py` and copy the following code into it.

```
def test1():
    total = 0
    while 1:
        total += 1

def test2():
    total = 0
    while True:
        total += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import dis, main
    dis.dis(main)
```

Running the code should produce the following output that shows how the code was actually compiled and what the generated *Python Virtual Machine Instructions* turned out to be.

```
Disassembly of test1:
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (total) 

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              13 (to 22) 

  4     >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (total) 
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1) 
             15 INPLACE_ADD          
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (total) 
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9 
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             25 RETURN_VALUE         

Disassembly of test2:
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (total) 

  8           6 SETUP_LOOP              13 (to 22) 

  9     >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (total) 
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1) 
             15 INPLACE_ADD          
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (total) 
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9 
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

The emitted PVMIs (byte codes) are exactly the same, so both loops should run without any difference in speed.

Comment: Worth pointing out that code is for Python 3

Comment: If you're going for raw arithmetic speed, Python is not the language for you.

Comment: It looks like your benchmarking harness is the main thing being tested here.

Comment: No, just playing around with Python to see how fast I could get it. Trying to run it without a looping check or a very fast looping check is the main challenge.

Comment: Why not use a mixture of integer operations from the dhrystone benchmark?  Why mess around with a novel approach when there are proven benchmarks?

Comment: @S.Lott: I was trying to learn how to write a fast loop that could be interrupted. Trying to figure out how to do that without a check or with a very fast check was one of the goals. Throwing an exception from another thread to crash a `while True: expression` loop was a nice discovery.

Comment: "an estimate of how fast some CPU operations may take" and "how to write a fast loop that could be interrupted" don't make a lot of sense together.  I can see one or the other.  I can't understand both.  Could you update the question to match your **real** objectives, please?

Comment: I just wanted to find out how many additions Python could make in a minute (and was very surprised how fast Python could do so). However, checking if a loop should terminate can take up valuable processor time, and figuring out how to minimize that time was essential in getting an accurate count. I had not thought that it would be possible to write a `while True: expression` loop (which is probably as fast as it is going to get in Python) that would terminate, but Amber showed me a nice way of doing so.

Comment: After reading http://www.johnloomis.org/NiosII/dhrystone/ECLDhrystoneWhitePaper.pdf and taking it into consideration, the **dhrystone benchmark** appears inferior to other methods of measuring speed. Fortunately, I was not interested in benchmarking Python as a whole. Finding out how many additions of one to a number can be made in a minute was my primary objective. Figuring out how to do that (`loop: number++; goto loop;`) was the challenging part. The disassembly shows that is the current case of the code, but that was only possible by using external code to interrupt a loop without a check.

Comment: On Python 2.x `while 1` and `while True` are *not* equivalent: https://gist.github.com/779350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About a 20-25% improvement, FWIW - but like others, I'd propose that Python incrementing integers probably isn't the best benchmarking tool.

```
def start(seconds):
    import time, _thread
    def stop(seconds):
        time.sleep(seconds)
        _thread.interrupt_main()
    total = 0
    _thread.start_new_thread(stop, (seconds,))
    try:
        while True:
            total += 1
    except:
        return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Testing the CPU speed ...')
    print('Relative speed:', start(60))
```

Comment: Thanks! That was an amazing speed-up. You know the `_thread` module better than I do. That is about the fastest loop one could write. Now I'll throw in the `gc` module to see if turning the garbage collector off will speed it up at all.

Comment: Running `gc.disable()` at the start and `gc.enable()` at the end of the timing function produced no appreciable speedup.

Comment: @Noctis Skytower: In CPython, objects are usually managed through reference counting. The `gc` module only gets involved to clean up reference cycles that aren't handled by the reference counter. This is why turnning off `gc` made no difference.

Comment: Sadly, the code only tests one core at a time. A revision (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4676959/216356) should run on all CPUs simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

I see almost the same but consistently better (~2%) results than [the @Amber's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676544/can-this-loop-be-sped-up-in-pure-python/4676593#4676593) on [my machine](https://gist.github.com/735259) on Python 3.1.2 for the code:

```
import signal

class Alarm(Exception):
    pass

def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Alarm

def jfs_signal(seconds):
    # set signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    # raise Alarm in `seconds` seconds
    signal.alarm(seconds)

    total = 0
    try:
        while 1:
            total += 1
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0) # disable the alarm
        return total
```

Here's variant that uses `subprocess` module to run interruptible loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# save it as `skytower.py` file
import atexit
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile
import time

def loop():
    @atexit.register
    def print_total():
        print(total)

    total = 0
    while 1:
        total += 1

def jfs_subprocess(seconds):
    # start process, redirect stdout/stderr
    f = tempfile.TemporaryFile() 
    p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-c",
                          "from skytower import loop; loop()"],
                         stdout=f, stderr=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
    # wait 
    time.sleep(seconds)

    # raise KeyboardInterrupt
    #NOTE: if it doesn't kill the process then `p.wait()` blocks forever
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) 
    p.wait() # wait for the process to terminate otherwise the output
             # might be garbled

    # return saved output
    f.seek(0) # rewind to the beginning of the file
    d = int(f.read())
    f.close()
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('total:', jfs_subprocess(60))
```

It is ~20% slower than the `signal.alarm()`'s variant on my machine.

Comment: Thanks! If the time weren't so late and I weren't so lazy, I'd jump over into Linux (from Windows) and test it. Maybe tomorrow. :-)

Comment: Yes, I think `while 1` is slightly faster than `while True`.

Comment: @kindall - interestingly, I had gotten the exact opposite results when testing the above code. `while True` ran slightly faster. Which mostly just goes to show that the two are actually identical, and it's just random variation.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise on learning more about Python and computers was satisfying. This is the final program:

```
def start(seconds, total=0):
    import _thread, time
    def stop():
        time.sleep(seconds)
        _thread.interrupt_main()
    _thread.start_new_thread(stop, ())
    try:
        while True:
            total += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Testing the CPU speed ...')
    print('Relative speed:', start(60))
```

Running it on Windows 7 Professional with a 2.16 GHz CPU produced the following output within IDLE:

```
Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 
on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Testing the CPU speed ...
Relative speed: 673991388
>>>
```

**Edit:** The code up above only runs on one core. The following program was written to fix that problem.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def main(seconds):
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Barrier, SimpleQueue, Process
    def get_all(queue):
        while not queue.empty():
            yield queue.get()
    args = seconds, Barrier(cpu_count()), SimpleQueue()
    processes = [Process(target=run, args=args) for _ in range(cpu_count())]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print('Relative speed:', sorted(get_all(args[-1]), reverse=True))

def run(seconds, barrier, queue):
    from time import sleep
    from _thread import interrupt_main, start_new_thread
    def terminate():
        sleep(seconds)
        interrupt_main()
    total = 0
    barrier.wait()
    start_new_thread(terminate, ())
    try:
        while True:
            total += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        queue.put(total)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(60)
```